# animating a menu opening to the proper height

Tags: javascript, html, css, user-interface, animation

I have a function that is meant to animate opening of a `ul` based navigation menu. unfortunately it just snaps into place instead of animating like it should.
Anyone know how to fix this?

```
function transitionComplete(event) {
    event.target.style.removeProperty("height")
    event.target.removeEventListener('transitionend', transitionComplete)
}

function openNavMenu() {
    let nav = document.querySelector("#main-nav")
    let menus = nav.querySelectorAll(".menus")

    for (let menu of menus) {
        // disable any modified height
        menu.style.height = 'initial'

        //measure height
        let expandedHeight = menu.offsetHeight

        // set the height back to zero in prep for animation.
        menu.style.height = '0px';

        menu.addEventListener('transitionend', transitionComplete, true)

 // HERE - I cannot figure out what I am supposed to do here
        // menu.style.height = expandedHeight
        requestAnimationFrame(() => {
            menu.style.height = expandedHeight + "px"
        })

    }
    nav.setAttribute(expanded, "true")
}
```

Here is the complete code including the script above, css and html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport"
          content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
        nav ul {
            list-style: none;
        }

        #main-nav {
            width: 80vw;
            background-color: #0000000A;
            display: flex;
            padding: 10px 0;
            margin: 20px auto;
        }

        #main-nav .menus {
            flex: 1;
            overflow: hidden;
            margin-left: max(0px, (100vw - 300px) / 4);
            padding-left: 20px;
            transition: 1s ease height;
        }

        #main-nav .menus li a {
            text-decoration: none;
            font-family: "Crimson Text", serif;
            letter-spacing: 2px;
            padding: 5px 5px 10px 0;
            margin: 5px 0;
            display: block;
        }

        #main-nav .menus > li > a {
            color: #7c6949;
        }

        #main-nav .menus > li ul {
            padding-left: 20px;
        }

        #main-nav .menus > li ul li:not(:last-child) a {
            border-bottom: 1px solid #0000000A;
        }

        #main-nav .control {
            background: none;
            border: none;
            display: flex;
            margin-right: 10px;
            background: orange;
            padding: 10px;
        }

        #main-nav[expanded] .control.open {
            display: none;
        }

        #main-nav:not([expanded]) .menus {
            height: 0;
        }

        #main-nav:not([expanded]) .control.close {
            display: none;
        }


        #footer-nav > .menus {
            letter-spacing: 2px;
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
        }

        #footer-nav > .menus > li ul {
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
        }

        #footer-nav > .menus > li ul li {
            display: inline-block;
        }

        #footer-nav > .menus > li ul li a {
            text-decoration: none;
            padding: 3px 0;
            text-transform: uppercase;
            display: inline-block;
            margin: 6px 0 0;
        }

        #footer-nav > .menus > li > a {
            display: none;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

<nav id="main-nav">
    <ul class="menus">
        <li>
            <a href="#">About</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="/">Biographies</a></li>
                <li><a href="/">Testimonials</a></li>
                <li><a href="/">FAQ</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Subscribe</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="/">Subscribe</a></li>
                <li><a href="/">Renew</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Contact</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="/">Contact Us</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <div class="controls">
        <button class="control open" onclick="openNavMenu()">
            open
        </button>
        <button class="control close" onclick="closeNavMenu()">
            close
        </button>
    </div>
</nav>

<script>
    const expanded = "expanded"

    function transitionComplete(event) {
        event.target.style.removeProperty("height")
        event.target.removeEventListener('transitionend', transitionComplete)
    }

    function openNavMenu() {
        let nav = document.querySelector("#main-nav")
        let menus = nav.querySelectorAll(".menus")

        for (let menu of menus) {
            // disable any modified height
            menu.style.height = 'initial'

            //measure height
            let expandedHeight = menu.offsetHeight

            // replace disabled styles
            menu.style.height = '0px';

            menu.addEventListener('transitionend', transitionComplete, true)

// HERE - What do I do?
            // menu.style.height = expandedHeight
            requestAnimationFrame(() => {
                menu.style.height = expandedHeight + "px"
            })

        }
        nav.setAttribute(expanded, "true")
    }

    function closeNavMenu() {
        let nav = document.querySelector("#main-nav")
        let menus = nav.querySelectorAll(".menus")
        nav.removeAttribute(expanded)
        for (let menu of menus) {
            menu.style.removeProperty("height");
        }
    }

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What is in your `assets/js/nav.js` file ? If I use your HTML without that script tag it animates opening fine - closing snaps shut.

Comment: @kevmc Ah, that file is what is listed below it. I copied the contents of that file into the script tag below to show it, but then neglected to remove the tag that points to the js file. I have edited the question and corrected this mistake. Thanks!

Comment: Here it is in a code pen: https://codepen.io/ssmsjm/pen/eYjZewv

Answer (score 0):

You can't animate from a property that has a value to a property value that isn't set.

Meaning, `menu.style.removeProperty("height")` this line removes the property and there for it has no value. By setting the height to 0 it will animate back to that.

```
function closeNavMenu() {
  let nav = document.querySelector("#main-nav");
  let menus = nav.querySelectorAll(".menus");
  nav.removeAttribute(expanded);
  for (let menu of menus) {
    menu.style.height = "0px"
  }
}
```

**Another topic**: 
There are probably opinions about this but I believe the majority of the industry do like this (also linters are setup default like it) but don't use `let` use `const`, use `let` for values you want to override and one example could be a `for` loop where you want to increment the i, `const` will assure you value won't get overridden.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The css rule `#main-nav:not([expanded]) .menus` does have `height: 0` so I am relying on that. and indeed the close animation is working fine. It is the opening navigation that is giving me issues. It is trickier because as you may be aware the final height must be known at the start of the animation, but it is not known until the element is fully open. I saw a technique where the element would be opened up and measured in between two frame renders (not visibly shown) and then the actual height can be used to make the animation. It's what I am trying to replicate here

Answer (score 0):

Interesting...

- in a chromimum browser (Chrome and Edge on my windows PC and Chrome
  on my Android phone) the animation works when opening the menu, but
  there is no animation when closing
- when viewed in FireFox the result is reversed, the closing animation works and the opening one doesn't

Chrome, I think, is suffering from the lack of a defined height at the start of the closing animation, as mentioned by @Dejan.S

Removing the `event.target.style.removeProperty("height", event.target)` from the `transitionComplete` callback fixes that issue

Unfortunately the `requestAnimationFrame` doesn't seem to have the desired effect in FireFox, but the old faithful trick of setting a zero timeout seems to work

```
setTimeout(() => {
                    menu.style.height = expandedHeight + "px"
            }, 0)
```